# How to console log in Sail.js to get the visiting routes or page header outputs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, console.log

If anyone could help me to find out how to do this? or what are the steps to get the visiting routes or page header outputs!

After creating a node.js app with framework Sails.js (1.web-app template NOT the 2.Empty one) and Run the app `sails lift`
Every page you visit you can see it in console. [Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IHgV.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I found a way, the did this by applying a hook.
Anyone can find it after launching a new sails app, then goto the

```
api/hooks/custom/index.js
```

It'll help anyone to analysis routes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correct you are looking for a middleware. That is where you can catch request headers and the path.

You can do that by defining a custom method in the `config/http.js` export object. And adding that method name to the order array in the same config file. The custom method itself can be used to catch all the information you're looking for. By the end your `config/http.js` would look something like this:

```
  module.exports = {
    order: [
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'bodyParser',
      'compress',
      'poweredBy',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',

      'logRequestInfo' // adding our new middleware
    ],

    logRequestInfo(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.headers); // loggin headers array
      console.log(req.path); // loggin request route
      next(); // executing next function to let server finish the request
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks @Timofey, I got it right I wan to print in the console the url path and how much time ago, where the user is roaming. Like the sails default sample app is doing. 
You can make a sample app with sails, and after run, you can see it in the console. 

But thanks again, for trying to solve it. but with your code I only get 
`host: 'localhost:1337',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 ....
   ....`

This not solve my purpose.